# Is it a bug of FireFox?

Tags: firefox

I think firefox's support to box model in CSS3 is soooooooooooooo poor...

I have encountered many problems involving box which works fine in Chrome and Safari..

Here is the latest problem:

it seems that FF does not support box with relative float..

here is the example, you can try it in jsFiddle:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="test">
        <div id="b1" class='item'></div>
        <div id="b2" class='item'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}

#test {
    pisition: relative;
    float:left;

    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;

    -moz-box-orient: $align;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;

    -webkit-box-orient: $align;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    box-orient: $align;
    box-pack: center;
    box-align: center;
}

.item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

#b1 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#b2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

when I remove the

```
pisition: relative;
float:left;
```

in the #test, everything is OK

but with 'float', the box model doesn't work...

Comment: I assume there's a question in all of this?

Comment: you didn't provide the jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using "CSS3".  You're using a combination of invalid CSS (there is no plan for a `display: box` in CSS), an early WebKit draft implementation of CSS3 Flexbox, and XUL boxes (which are completely unrelated to CSS3 Flexbox and to what WebKit implements).

XUL boxes are not allowed to be floated; when you float them they become blocks, because floating changes display values in CSS.

Comment: I found it. FF changes display to inline-block.so box no longer works...it's my wrong. sorry..thanks!